# Can we integrate PHP file in bigcommerce?

Tags: php, api, integration, bigcommerce, jet

I want to fetch bigcommerce products to integrate it on jet.com. Through API, Products are successfully fetched from bigcommerce. But I created a PHP file in my local server for API. Now I dont know how can I use that PHP file in bigcommerce. Is there any way to upload a php file in bigcommerce or I have to run it through another domain or server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to run it on another server. You can't upload server side code to BC in the form of php, rb, etc.